# Instantiating a SoundFile object within a class in Processing

Tags: audio, processing

I am attempting to create an instance of the [SoundFile](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/sound/SoundFile.html) type inside of another class in Processing (the latest version, 3.0a10). I can easily play a sound that is defined outside of a class, as follows:

```
import processing.sound.*;

SoundFile clickSound;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  clickSound = new SoundFile(this, "bike-passing-by.wav");
}

void draw() {
  clickSound.play();
}
```

However, I run into trouble when I attempt to create a SoundFile instance from inside a class. A simplified example of this would be:

```
import processing.sound.*;

SomeSound fx;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  fx = new SomeSound();
}

void draw() {
  fx.play();
}

class SomeSound {
  SoundFile clickSound;

  SomeSound() {
    clickSound = new SoundFile(this, "bike-passing-by.wav");
  }

  void play() {
    clickSound.play();
  }

}
```

The error I receive is that `"The constructor SoundFile(soundTest.SomeSound, String) is undefined"`. In the Processing reference for SoundFile, it states that the constructor is defined as `SoundFile(parent, path)`. The parent parameter is supposed to be `PApplet: typically use "this"`.

I therefore tried a number of options to replace this line:
`clickSound = new SoundFile(this, "bike-passing-by.wav");`

I tried replacing `this` with `super`:
`clickSound = new SoundFile(super, "bike-passing-by.wav");`

and `PApplet`:
`clickSound = new SoundFile(PApplet, "bike-passing-by.wav");`

but only manage to produce different errors. Any advice on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how to call the `setup()` and  `draw()` that must mention in the question.

Comment: Processing automatically calls setup() once, and runs draw() in an infinite loop for the duration the program runs.

Comment: you this both function must include in the same class otherwise its not working as usually you question. ill put one method in answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is happening because, like you said, you need access to the `PApplet` instance that is automatically created for you in your Processing sketch. When you're in another class, the `this` keyword refers to the instance of that class, not the sketch's `PApplet` instance.

If your class is inside your main sketch (not in another tab), then you can do this:

```
import processing.sound.*;

SomeSound fx;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  fx = new SomeSound();
}

void draw() {
  fx.play();
}

class SomeSound {
  SoundFile clickSound;

  SomeSound() {
    clickSound = new SoundFile(NameOfYourSketch.this, "bike-passing-by.wav");
  }

  void play() {
    clickSound.play();
  }

}
```

The only line you really care about is this one:

```
clickSound = new SoundFile(NameOfYourSketch.this, "bike-passing-by.wav");
```

This syntax might look strange, but you can get to the sketch-level `this` by using `NameOfYourSketch.this`. Under the hood, this is because your sketch is compiled into a Java class, and classes inside your main sketch window are non-static inner classes of that class.

If your class is in another tab, that approach won't work, because classes in their own tab are compiled into their own top-level non-inner Java classes, so they don't have access to the sketch-level `this` variable. Instead, you'd have to pass it into the class:

```
import processing.sound.*;

SomeSound fx;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  fx = new SomeSound(this);
}

void draw() {
  fx.play();
}

class SomeSound {
  SoundFile clickSound;

  SomeSound(PApplet p) {
    clickSound = new SoundFile(p, "bike-passing-by.wav");
  }

  void play() {
    clickSound.play();
  }

}
```

Notice that the `SomeSound` constructor takes a `PApplet` argument, which it can then pass into the `SoundFile` constructor. To supply that `PApplet` instance to the `SomeSound` constructor, you can then use the sketch-level `this` keyword.

Note that this second approach will work if your class is defined in its own tab or if it's inside the sketch tab, and it's a little less "coupled" with your sketch, so it's probably preferable over the first approach.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed to know!! Works like a charm. I appreciate the explanation as to why it works, as well as the actual syntax.

Answer (score -1):

```
import processing.sound.*;

class callerClass{
  SomeSound fx;

  void setup() {
    size(600, 600);
    this.fx = new SomeSound();
  }

  void draw() {
    this.fx.play();
  }
}
class SomeSound {
  SoundFile clickSound;

  SomeSound() {
    clickSound = new SoundFile(this, "bike-passing-by.wav");
  }

  void play() {
    clickSound.play();
  }

}
```

- In this method instance `fx` is not destroy so try this method if any problem must comment.